# Как сделать так, что бы когда боту писали обычным текстом то он не реагировал, но если написать тот же самый текст но с # то он ответил

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот, chat

Пишу бота клон ChatGPT на Python с помощью aiogram надо что бы общение с ним выглядело так:

Юзер: Привет

Бот: *ничего

Юзер: #Привет

Бот: Здраствуйте

Answer (score 0):

Например так

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def cmd_answer(message: types.Message):
    if message.text.startswith('#'):
        await message.answer('Здравствуйте')
    else:
        pass
```